# How to map YAML file data into multiple java models?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

How to map the data from a single YAML file to multiple bean objects? I am using *snakeyaml*

```
**variables.yml:**
Apple:
   A1: a1
   A2: a2
Mango:
   M1: m1
   M2: m2

**Java Model Classes:**
Apple apple = new Apple(a1, a2);
Mango mango = new Mango(m1, m2);
Fruit fruit = new Fruit(apple, mango);
```

Right now I could get the individual data as below:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("variables.yaml"));
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        Map<String, Object> yamlMaps = yaml.load(inputStream);
        Map<String, Object> appleData = (Map<String, Object>) yamlMaps.get("Header");
        Map<String, Object> mangoData = (Map<String, Object>) yamlMaps.get("Content");
```

**But I want to load these data into the Fruit object.**

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-providing-the-top-level-type

Comment: @tgdavies yeah! I tried it using TypeDescription, but it gives an error: "Cannot create property=Header for JavaBean=Fruit"

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question is using `@ConfigurationProperties` from spring-boot.

---

Sample Code to use `@ConfigurationProperties`

`SampleApplication.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    Fruit fruit;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(fruit);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`Fruit.java`

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Fruit {

    @JsonProperty("apple")
    Apple apple;

    @JsonProperty("mango")
    Mango mango;

    public Fruit() {
    }

    // getters, setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fruit{" +
                "apple=" + apple +
                ", mango=" + mango +
                '}';
    }
}
```

`Apple.java`

```
public class Apple {

    @JsonProperty("A1")
    String A1;

    @JsonProperty("A2")
    String A2;

    // getters, setters, toString...
```

`Mango.java`

```
public class Mango {

    @JsonProperty("M1")
    String M1;

    @JsonProperty("M2")
    String M2;

    public Mango() {
    }

    public Mango(String m1, String m2) {
        M1 = m1;
        M2 = m2;
    }
    // constructors, getters, setters, toString...
```

`application.yml`

```
apple:
  A1: a1
  A2: a2
mango:
  M1: m1
  M2: m2
```

After running the application I got the below result.

```
...
Fruit{apple=Apple{A1='a1', A2='a2'}, mango=Mango{M1='m1', M2='m2'}}
...
```

Comment: Saravanakrishnan Pk ::: How did you load the yml file? Did you set the TypeDescription for the Fruit class?